# Timer trigger enable condition match css selector isn't working

Tags: css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I'm having a problem with css selector in Google tag manager Timer trigger. Hoping someone can help. When users press on a play button, the timer will be triggered and fire a tag only when it's playing. The reason i use Timer trigger is to see how long the live music has been listened roughly until users press stop or close the page.  I have added a timer trigger in GTM with click element match css selector but it's not enabling the timer. Sometimes the click node is "svg". Sometimes click node is "use". If i only use page path contains /path/, it works. `button.c-hero-output__control *,svg.c-icon.c-hero-output__control-icon,svg.c-icon.c-hero-output__control-icon *`
is_playing (in the timer trigger image) is a return value from a function in GTM and working well.

[image: nested element in html]
[image: click SVGSVGelement in GTM preview]
[image: click SVGUseelement in GTM preview]
[image: timer trigger settings in GTM]

```html
<div class="c-hero-output__info"><button type="button" class="c-hero-output__control" data-player-target="playButton" data-action="click->player#play" data-player-audio-url-param="https://fdskjfsfds/radio.mp3?Device=LivePlayer" data-player-audio-type-param="audio/mp3" data-player-title-param="music" data-player-subtitle-param="radio" data-player-image-url-param="https://aiircdn.com/5d.png" data-player-is-live-param="true" data-player-is-adswizz-enabled-param="true" data-player-service-id-param="3211" aria-label="Play Radio" aria-pressed="false" data-aria-play-label="PlayRadio">
                        <svg class="c-icon c-hero-output__control-icon" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
                            <use href="#icon-play" xlink:href="#icon-play" data-player-target="playButtonIcon"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </button><div>..........</div></div>
```

---

I used the idea you gave me @darrelltw. This is what've done so far.
The problem is the timer will keep going event it's not playing.  (not sure how to write in js)

- 1 variable: to get the value if the player is playing
- 2 triggers: play btn clicked on the certain btn, custom event isplaying equal to true.
- 2 tags:

  - custom html tag with setInterval 10 sec timer and certain btn click trigger(click element.match css selector.`[data-player-target],[data-player-target] *,.c-hero-output__control,.c-hero-output__control *,button.c-hero-output__control svg,button.c-hero-output__control svg *,  button.c-hero-output__control use,button.c-hero-output__control use *`). The problem with this tag. Every time the certain btn clicked, it will be triggered so the duplicated javascript will appear. I did add trigger group of btn clicked and isplaying, however, the timer won't be triggered.
  - GA4 event tag with custom event trigger

    ```js
    <script>  
        //var timertracking;
           // function to track time
          function playerTrackTime() {
            currentTime = Date.now();
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            dataLayer.push({'event':'10secInterval',
                            'timer_currenttime':currentTime,
                           });
          }
      if ({{is_playing}}==true) {
        //playerInterval();
        setInterval(playerTrackTime, 10000);
      } else {
       //clearInterval(timertracking);
      }
    </script>
    ```

Comment: Copy html around your button to here.

Comment: Hi @BNazaruk, thanks for replying. i've added html in the content above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `Timer trigger` can not be triggered by a click event.

The `Timer Trigger` will only load on the pageView.

In this case. You need to write some JS and use the `setTimeout` to meet the requirement.

Tag : customHtml , fire the setTimeout
Trigger : allClick , use the css selector you provided.

I will push datalayer in the customHtml if I am doing it.

---

Here is the code example. It will push datalayer in 30 seconds after the user click the button

(If the trigger is set to click the button)

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event : "some_event"
  });
}, 30000);
```

In this way you need to set a time to track if user reaches the time.
Like this example, **only user stays more than 30 seconds after click then they will be tracked**.

It is not something like you can track how long the user listened the music before they leaved. It could be done but required a deeper understanding for the JS. Not really recommend for this stage.

Comment: Hi @darrelltw, i'm not good at JS. Could you give me more details? Do i use setTimeout in JS or in customHtml ? thanks

Comment: The reason i use Timer trigger is to see how long the live music has been listened roughly. Will setTimeout work the same way?